# Custom DateTimePicker value isn't saved in Application Settings

Tags: vb.net, date, datetimepicker, settings

UPDATED :

I want to save a Custom DateTimePicker.Value in my Application Settings.
The custom format is : dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss, instead of dd/MM/yyyy
The field i've created in the application settings parameters is LASTSAVE (DATE / APPLICATION)

When I try to link in the ApplicationSettings/PropertyBinding ... VALUE with my field LASTSAVE, i have an error :

> The Value '01/01/0001 00:00:00' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' must
>   be ... 'MinDate' et 'MaxDate'.
>
> Name of the parameter : Value

I then entered the MIN and MAX date in the properties of my control DATETIMEPICKER.
I have also put into the  properties Value a start date like 23/11/2011 12:00:00 ;

However, when i retry to link in the ApplicationSettings/PropertyBinding ... value to LASTSAVE / I have the same error (The Value '01/01/0001 00:00:00' is not valid for 'Value'. ). I've saved all, do a process that put a value in the datetimepicker.value, but it's not saved, cause not linked.

A solution please ?

Comment: We're probably going to need to see the code to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

'01/01/0001 00:00:00' is DateTime.Empty, the default value for a DateTime that hasn't been set. Is there a value in your application settings to begin with? Are you handling the case where the value has not yet been set?

Comment: @brian anderson : Hello Brian,